# エラーの意味がわかりません：Couldn't match type

Tags: haskell

昇順に並んでいる整数リストasに、昇順を維持したまま新しい整数xを挿入する関数`interSortedList(as,x)`を定義したいのですが、何回プログラムを実行してもコンパイルエラーが出てしまいます。

私は以下のようにプログラムしました。

```
insertSortedList([],x)=x
insertSortedList(a:as,x)=if x<a then x:a:as else sort(as,x)
```

＊関数sortはすでに定義積みなので割愛。

片方のリストが空だった場合には、そのまま新しい整数xを挿入するだけなので、xと定義する。(`insertSortedList([],x)=x`）
両方のリストが空ではない場合、もし、挿入する数字xがa未満の場合、xはリストのどの値よりも小さいので、先頭に挿入する。そうでない場合、リストの残りasの中に挿入する。（`insertSortedList(a:as,x)=if x<a then x:a:as else sort(as,x)`）

このように考えたのですが、次のようなエラーが出てきました。

```
Prelude> :l sample1002.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( sample1002.hs, interpreted )

sample1002.hs:329:54: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[t]’
                  with actual type ‘([[t]], [t])’
    • In the first argument of ‘sort’, namely ‘(as, x)’
      In the expression: sort (as, x)
      In the expression: if x < a then x : a : as else sort (as, x)
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: [t] (bound at sample1002.hs:329:23)
        as :: [[t]] (bound at sample1002.hs:329:20)
        a :: [t] (bound at sample1002.hs:329:18)
        insertSortedList :: ([[t]], [t]) -> [t]
          (bound at sample1002.hs:328:1)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

どこがおかしいのでしょうか、ご回答お願いします。

Comment: 「エラーの意味がわかりません」というタイトルだと抽象的すぎますので、質問の概要が分かるようなタイトルにしましょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず `insertSortedList` の型を考えてみましょう。引数の1つめは昇順のリストで2つめは新規に挿入したい値、そして返り値は挿入済みのリストとなります。これを Haskell の型で表すと（要素が `Int` であるとするなら）次のようになります。（おそらくプログラミング初心者であると想定して `Ord` 型クラスは使わないようにしています。）

```hs
insertSortedList :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
```

さてここで質問の実装を見てみましょう。

```hs
insertSortedList([],x)=x
```

引数に関してですが、`([],x)` とするとタプルを受ける1つの引数になってしまうので `[] x` として2引数とするのが必須ではありませんが一般的です。

次に返り値に注目すると `x` となっています。これは `Int` であるので `insertSortedList` がリストを返すということと矛盾します。

では何を返すべきなのかを考えると、`x` が要素に1つあるリストを返すべきです。なので正しくは下記となります。

```hs
insertSortedList [] x = [x]
```

空リストで場合でない定義は次のようにします。

```hs
insertSortedList (a:as) x = if x < a then x:a:as else insertSortedList as x
```

変更点は、引数をタプルでなくしました。else 節の `sort` を `insertSortedList` にしました。

これでコンパイルエラーはなくなりました。

実行してみると次のようになります。

```hs
> insertSortedList [1, 2, 5] 3
[3,5]
```

期待する返り値は `[1, 2, 3, 5]` のはずです。何かバグがあります。

答は空リストでない定義の else 節で `a` が消えている（使われていない）ことにあります。修正すると次のようになります。

```hs
insertSortedList [] x = [x]
insertSortedList (a:as) x = if x < a then x:a:as else a:insertSortedList as x
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。実際にコンパイルを実行して動作することを確認しました。